# How do I print everything from a dictionary nested in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror

```
shopItems = {
    "Item1":{
    "lvlReq":10,
    "Cost":100,
    "Stock":1},

    "Item2":{
    "lvlReq":20,
    "Cost":200,
    "Stock":2},
    }

for key in shopItems.iterkeys():
    print key,
    for items in shopItems[key]:
        print items,
        for values in shopItems[key][items]:
            print values
```

This gives me the error: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

And I want it to print out:

> Item1 lvlReq 10 Cost 100 Stock 1
>
> Item2 lvlReq 20 Cost 200 Stock 2

Comment: You're having three nested loops while your data 'depth' is only two levels.

Comment: Well if i remove values, it only shows "item1 cost lvlreq stock item2 cost lvlreq stock

Comment: You can see the loop prints the second level keys (e.g. cost), which variable then hold these values? How can you use it to print the values (e.g. 100) as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's look at what your existing code does.

- Each `key` is a top-level key, like "Item1".
- So `shopItems[key]` is one of those inner dicts, like {"lvlReq":10, "Cost":100, "Stock":1}`.
- So each `items` is a key in one of those inner dicts, like `lvlReq`. You should be seeing that from your `print items`.
- So each `shopItems[key][items]` is a value in one of those inner dicts, like `10`.
- So each `values` is an element of one of those values, like… oops, 10 isn't an iterable, it doesn't *have* any elements.

So you just went one step too far.

---

What you want to print out is the keys and values of those inner dicts, right?

```
for key in shopItems.iterkeys():
    print key,
    for items in shopItems[key]:
        print items, shopItems[key][items],
    print
```

---

You could make this clearer by giving these variables names that correspond to what they actually are, and by iterating over keys when you want keys and key-value pairs when you want key-value pairs:

```
for itemname, itemdict in shopItems.iteritems():
    print itemname,
    for propname, propvalue in itemdict.iteritems():
        print propname, propvalue,
    print
```

---

Either way, you'll get something like this:

```
Item2 Cost 200 lvlReq 20 Stock 2
Item1 Cost 100 lvlReq 10 Stock 1
```

Of course that's not in the same order you wanted—but that's because dictionaries don't have any inherent order; looping over a dictionary always gives you the elements in whatever order it feels like giving you.

If that's not acceptable, you might want to use an `OrderedDict` instead of a `dict`, or you might want to call `sorted` somewhere, or you might want to go through the key that you know you want in the order you want them instead of whatever's there in whatever order. For example (maybe not the exact behavior you want, but you should be able to figure it out from here):

```
for itemname, itemdict in sorted(shopItems.iteritems()):
    print itemname,
    for propname in ('lvlReq', 'Cost', 'Stock'):
        print propname, itemdict[propname],
    print
```

Now the rows show up in sorted order (so `Item1` is before `Item2`—but then `Item11` is *also* before `Item2`…), and the columns are always the same `lvlReq Cost Stock` in that order.

Answer (score 3):

Without asking why, here is one way using list-comprehensions:

```
for k,v in shopItems.items():
    print(' '.join([k]+[' '.join(map(str,i)) for i in v.items()]))
```

Returns:

```
Item1 lvlReq 10 Cost 100 Stock 1
Item2 lvlReq 20 Cost 200 Stock 2
```

Comment: it does ... sorry. my prints always trip me up when using python2 and printing unwanted () .. yours does not. going to investigate that

Answer (score 1):

Less elegant than @AntonvBR, but sticking with your code setup...

```
   In [59]: shopItems = {
        ...:     "Item1":{
        ...:     "lvlReq":10,
        ...:     "Cost":100,
        ...:     "Stock":1},
        ...: 
        ...:     "Item2":{
        ...:     "lvlReq":20,
        ...:     "Cost":200,
        ...:     "Stock":2},
        ...:     }
        ...: 
        ...: for key in shopItems:
        ...:     print(key, end=' ')
        ...:     for items, values in shopItems[key].items():
        ...:         print(items, values, end=' ')
        ...:     print()
        ...:     
        ...:     
        ...:         
    Item1    lvlReq   10  Cost   100  Stock   1
    Item2    lvlReq   20  Cost   200  Stock   2
```

---

Edit for python2:

```
for key in shopItems:
    print key,
    for items, values in shopItems[key].items():
    print items, values,  
    print ""
```

Comment: its python 2.7 from the OPs usage of `print` - yours is nice, but 3.x

Comment: at least i wasn't the only one to miss that... :-s

Comment: Your Python2 code is attempting to repeat all of the "soft-space" magic that `,` already does, which means the code is more complicated than it needs to be, and has extra spaces all over.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
for key in shopItems:
    print(key, end=" ")
    for items in shopItems[key]:
        print(items, end=" ")
        print(shopItems[key][items], end=" ")
    print()
```